# How to delete an issue in SonarQube Database?

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube only provide a configuration to delete all closed issues. Is that a possible to delete a certain issue in sonar database?

And how to make sure the amount of the issues under Resolution in SonarQube UI under tab Issues will be changed after deleted? (I tried to delete some record in sonar table "issues", but the amount of the issues wasn't change)

Please help provide the sql to delete certain issue. Thanks!

---

[Thanks n_stan's reply! 
This idea is raised by a strange problem that I found in SonarQube. Fixed issues shows under Unresolved. Click me to see the screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2eGA.png)

Comment: I got a solution in another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598965/sonarqube-wont-refresh-after-deleted-closed-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's hardly any good reason for going and deleting things directly in the database (that would be asking for problems further down the road).

Issues can be resolved for good by marking either as `False Positive` or `Won't Fix`. See documentation [Reviewing Issues](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Reviewing+Issues#ReviewingIssues-Markinganissuefalsepositiveorwon%27tfix) and [Issue Lifecycle](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/user-guide/issues/#issues-lifecycle).

Comment: There is at least one good reason to delete issues: when writing a custom plugin if you have a bug in your plugin, you can end with issues you can't remove after having fixed the plugin. This is what we exeprienced and the only fix we found was to remove the rule, fix it, then re-add it using a different key. Otherwise the 10-months-old status was comming back each time as if the rule wasn't fixed.