# SonarQube won't refresh after deleted closed issues?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

After configed "Delete closed issues after" and "Keep only one snapshot a day after" to 1 under "Settings > General Settings > General > Database Cleaner", and rerun analyze. The numbers under Issues are not correctly.

Is there a way to refresh or config something to make sure the numbers are correct?

Thanks!

---

Here is the example. There are 16 issues in Unresolved. I checked all issues in the detail window, but only got 9 issues.
[Click me to see the screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zK1y.png)

Comment: Okay, someone given me suggestion, I tested and it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, someone given me a suggestion, I tested and it works for me.

Steps:

- Stop the SonarQube server
- Delete the folder under data/es in the SonarQube
- Start the server again